# obtener valor de variable de jsp en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

como paso el valor de una variable declarada en una jsp a un archivo js para modificarla y volverla a pasar a la jsp.

archivo jsp

```
 <body>
       <%!  int contador = 3; %>
        <div class = "container">
            <div  class="page-header page-header2 text-left">
                <img src="resource/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive " alt="Responsive image"/>
            </div>
```

necesito cambiar ese valor de la variable contador desde un archivo javaScript con una funcion jquery

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar una variable de JSP a JavaScript y pueda ser usada en el código, te basta con escribirla en la página dentro de una etiqueta `script`:

```
<%!  int contador = 3; %>
<script>
var miVar = <%= contador %>;
alert("El valor del contador es " + miVar);
</script>
```

Luego para pasar la variable JavaScript a JSP podrías usar AJAX. Que con jQuery sería algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mipagina.jsp",
    data: { contador: miVar }
});
```

Pero ojo: así se pasarán los datos de JavaScript a JSP de manera asíncrona. Que yo sepa, no se puede hacer de manera síncrona (ejecutar JSP, a mitad de ejecución realizar algo en JavaScript, y continuar con JSP). Eso no sería posible.